# AGGrid - Aggregation, Filtering

Tags: ag-grid

In agGrid, I have an aggregation which is based on two columns. When I apply filter, the aggregates based on two columns are not updated. There is no problem with sum, max, min aggregate functions as all these are based on same column.

here is the steps I follow,
Group by a Column --> Value Aggregation --> Weighted Avg(Custom Aggregation) --> Add a filter.

When I add a filter after weighted avg aggregation calculation, the new weighted avg is not refreshed.

I have this aggregate calculated using a valueGetter function (as in the code below).

Is there a way to update the aggregates which comes from a valueGetter function when I modify the filter?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vijay.

```
function weightedAverageGetter(params) {
        var col = params.column.colId.split('.')[1];
        var value = 0;
        if (params.data){
            value = params.data.qli?params.data.qli[col]:0;
            if (col == 'P1prime__c' || col == 'P2Prime__c'){
                value = Math.ceil(value);
            }
        }

        var avgW = 0;
        if (params.node){
            var sumVal = 0;
            var sumQty = 0;
            for (var node in params.node.allLeafChildren){
                var nodeValue = params.node.allLeafChildren[node];
                var val = 0;
                var qty = 0;
                if (nodeValue.data){
                    val = nodeValue.data.qli?nodeValue.data.qli[col]:0;
                    qty = nodeValue.data.qli?parseFloat(nodeValue.data.qli.Quantity):0;
                }
                if (typeof val !=='undefined' && val != '' && typeof qty !=='undefined' && qty != '') {
                    sumQty += qty;
                    sumVal += qty*val;
                }
            }
            avgW = sumVal/sumQty;
        }

        avgW = Math.round(avgW * 100) / 100;

        if(!params.column.aggregationActive || Number.isNaN(avgW)){
            avgW = '';
        }
        return params.data?value:avgW;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Vijay, please add samples of your code, so we can see what you are actually doing, which may differ from your intent. Explain what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: It is best to edit your question to include the new information, as most people won't read through the comments for details. 
Also code and other content can be formatted better as part of the question. Also, I think you will need more code detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just edited the main post  -:)

Comment: @Vijay are you using ag grid aggregation which is enterprise feature or trying to make your custom aggregate function?

Comment: @PratikBhat, yes I do use aggregation from enterprise features, but this problem is related to the custom aggregate function. I use valueGetter function, as I need to access values from other columns. Thanks